# Autocad "edgesurf" equivalent in Blender?

Tags: modeling, mesh

How I can do an operation in blender like Autocad's *edgesurf*?

In Autocad, edgesurf creates a mesh between four contiguous edges or curves:

[image]

Access methods from autocad:

- Button
- Ribbon:  Mesh Modeling tabPrimitives panelModeling, Meshes, Edge Surface
- Menu: DrawModelingMeshesEdge Mesh
- Command entry: edgesurf

Summary:

> Select four adjoining edges that define the mesh. The edges can be
>   lines, arcs, splines, or open polylines. The edges must touch at their
>   endpoints to form a single, closed loop.

Answer (score 15):

You're looking for the **[Grid Fill](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Faces#Grid_Fill)** tool.

Grid fill is accessible with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> *<kbd>Grid fill</kbd>* or via the *3D View header > Mesh > Faces > Grid Fill*.

[image: Two edge loops selected, before applying Grid Fill]
[image: The result of applying Grid Fill to the previous scene]